# Android - PDFTron - draw annotation in zoom in mode

Tags: android, annotations, pdftron

I'm using the PdfTron SDK and i'm trying to draw annotation after the user doing zoom in, the annotation need to be in the side of the book (the third pic) but when we do zoom in it's drawing in the center of the book (pic 1 and 2).

Example with zoom (the wrong state):

[image]

[image]

Example without zoom (the right state):

[image]

right now i'm using the function **convPagePtToScreenPt** but it's drawing the annotation properly just if the user doesn't making zoom in.
Does somebody knows in which function is suppose to use?

This is my code :

```
public synchronized void drawAnnotation(AnnotationData annotationData){

    if (annotationData == null) {
        return;
    }   


    AnnotationType annotationType = annotationData.getType();

    if (annotationType == null) {
        return;
    }

    ToolManager.Tool tool = mToolManager.createTool(ToolManager.e_text_annot_create, null);
        if (tool instanceof StickyNoteCreate) {
            StickyNoteCreate annotStickyCreate = (StickyNoteCreate) tool;
            Point point;
            double[] pts;
            double[] ptsForScreenSize = {0, 0};
            int orientation = mContext.getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;
            if (mPDFView != null) {
                if (orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
                     ptsForScreenSize = mPDFView.convScreenPtToPagePt((double) BookReader.SCREEN_WIDTH, (double) BookReader.SCREEN_HEIGHT, annotationData.getPage());
                } else {
                    ptsForScreenSize = mPDFView.convScreenPtToPagePt((double) BookReader.SCREEN_HEIGHT, (double) BookReader.SCREEN_WIDTH, annotationData.getPage());
                    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(annotationData.getStartLoc()) && !TextUtils.isEmpty(annotationData.getEndLoc()) && mPDFView != null) {
                        //if we have an annotation for text
                        pts = mPDFView.convPagePtToScreenPt(annotationData.getStartX(), annotationData.getStartY(), annotationData.getPage());
                    } else {
                        //if we have an annotation for Page
                        pts = new double[]{0, 0};
                    }                   
                    ptsForScreenSize = mPDFView.convPagePtToScreenPt(ptsForScreenSize[0] - INT_ANNO_PADDING, ptsForScreenSize[1], annotationData.getPage());
                    final AnnotationData noteTextHighlight = new AnnotationData(annotationData);
                    //we don't need to set UniqueId for this highlight annotation
                    noteTextHighlight.setUniqueId(null);
                    highlightSelectedText(noteTextHighlight);
                    double marginY = BookReader.SCREEN_HEIGHT * 0.015;
                    point = new Point(ptsForScreenSize[0], pts[1] + marginY);
                    annotStickyCreate.createNoteIconOnPage(annotationData, point);
                }
            }
    }       
}


  public void createNoteIconOnPage(AnnotationData annotationData, Point noteIconPoint) {
    KsLog.d("IsBookReaderAviliable","createNoteIconOnPage : " + BookReader.isBookReaderVisible());
    if(BookReader.isBookReaderVisible()){
        try {
            mPDFView.docLock(true);
            PDFDoc pdfDoc = mPDFView.getDoc();
            double[] pts = mPDFView.convScreenPtToPagePt(noteIconPoint.x, noteIconPoint.y, annotationData.getPage());
            Point p = new Point(pts[0], pts[1]);
            com.pdftron.pdf.annots.Text text = com.pdftron.pdf.annots.Text.create(pdfDoc, p);
            text.setUniqueID(annotationData.getUniqueId());
            //creating the annotation appearance - icon

            // Let's create an appearance for the annotation using an image
            ElementBuilder builder = new ElementBuilder();
            ElementWriter writer = new ElementWriter();
            writer.begin(pdfDoc);

            Image image = Image.create(pdfDoc, annotationData.getDrawable());

            int w = image.getImageWidth(), h = image.getImageHeight();

            Element element = builder.createImage(image, 0, 0, w, h);

            writer.writePlacedElement(element);

            writer.writeElement(builder.createTextBegin(Font.create(pdfDoc, Font.e_times_roman), 12));

            writer.writeElement(element);
            writer.writeElement(builder.createTextEnd());

            Obj appearance = writer.end();
            appearance.putRect("BBox", 0.1, 0.1, w, h);
            text.setAppearance(appearance);

        /*
        The left icons spouse to be bigger the the regular icons
         */
            if (annotationData.getType() == AnnotationData.AnnotationType.LINK && (annotationData.getShard() == AnnotationData.LEFT_LINK_A || annotationData.getShard() == AnnotationData.LEFT_LINK_B)) {
                text.setRect(new Rect(pts[0], pts[1], pts[0] + 30, pts[1] + 30));
            }

            if (annotationData.getType() == AnnotationData.AnnotationType.NOTE) {
                text.setContents(AnnotationData.NOTE_TYPE_CONTENTS);
            } else if (annotationData.getType() == AnnotationData.AnnotationType.LINK) {
                text.setContents(AnnotationData.LINK_TYPE_CONTENTS);
            }

            KsLog.d("createNoteIconOnPage","getPage() " + annotationData.getPage());
            Page page = pdfDoc.getPage(annotationData.getPage());
            if (page != null) {
                page.annotPushBack(text);
            }


            mAnnotPushedBack = true;
            mAnnot = text;
            mAnnotPageNum = annotationData.getPage();
            KsLog.d("createNoteIconOnPage","mDownPageNum " + mAnnotPageNum);

            buildAnnotBBox();
            mPDFView.update(mAnnot, mAnnotPageNum);
            raiseAnnotationAddedEvent(mAnnot, mAnnotPageNum);

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Log.e(PDFTronReader.TAG, ex.toString());
            mNextToolMode = ToolManager.e_pan;

        } finally {
            mPDFView.docUnlock();

        }
        mPDFView.waitForRendering();
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you post the code you use to add the annotation to the page. Also, please include the x,y values you are using to place it on the right side. How do you determine these coordinates?

Comment: Hey Ryan, i edit my post, please check it.

Comment: To clarify, when you first add the annotation, it is on the right side of the page, which is where you want it. But then when you zoom in, it "jumps" to the middle of the page? From then on it is always in the same location? Or it continues to jump around? In the first two screen shots the annotation is in the same location.

Comment: No, the annotation is not "jump" to the middle of the page. in the first two screen shots i added annotation after i do zoom in and in the third is without zooming in. i want that the annotation is always will draw like the third screen shot (even after zooming in).

Comment: In that case, an annotation would not work for you, since they are positioned relative to the page. So as a user zooms/pans, the annotation moves (so as to always be on the same location on the page). What happens, instead of zooming, the user scrolls up/down? Do you want the annotation to remain stationary, or does the annotation also move up down? It is still unclear what you want to happen on zoom/pan. Perhaps another screen shot showing what you want to happen.

Comment: It's very simple, i want that the annotations will draw at the side of the book (right side  - like we see in the third pic) no meter if the user is do zoom in our zoom out. it means that if the user doing zoom in and add annotation he will not see the annotation until he will do zoom out and than he will see it at  the side of the book.

Answer (score 1):

The following code will place an annotation on the right side of any page, 1 inch from the top.

```
Matrix2D mtx = page.getDefaultMatrix(true).inverse();
double x1 = page.getPageWidth() - 25; // this is the width as the a user sees it (rotated). 20 is the width of a Text annotation
double y1 = 72; // not clear how you decide the vertical placement. In this example, this 1 inch from the top as the user views the page. If you have the value from the bottom, switch the boolean value argument in GetDefaultMatrix
mtx.mult(ref x1, ref y1);
com.pdftron.pdf.Annots.Text txt = com.pdftron.pdf.Text.create(doc, new Point(x1, y1));
page.annotPushBack(txt);
```

Regarding your code, there appeared to be confusion over Screen and Page coordinates. For example, for `ptsForScreenSize` on one line of you pass in the results of `ConvScreenPtToPagePt`, and in another line, you pass in the results of `ConvPagePtToScreenPt`.

Comment: Did you get a chance to try out my answer?